# How to disable submit button until specific dropdown listitem selected?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

> ** I want to disable button when "--Select--" list item will selected**
>   here's my full code.

i use validation  ValidationGroup="AddUser" and bind Button,dropdown and textbox.

I tried a lot but i can't find my solution,please help.

Thanks in advance.

```html
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label>User Name</label>
       <asp:TextBox ID="tbUser" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Username" OnTextChanged="tbUser_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="User" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,16}$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Username must contain minimum 4,Max 16 characters." Style="color: darkred;"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator  runat="server" ControlToValidate="User" >
         <div style="color:darkred;">
           <span class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" style="color:darkred">
           </span>
         </div>

        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

      </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
   <label>Role</label>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="Role" class="form-control" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRole_SelectedIndexChanged">
     <asp:ListItem Value="0">---Select---</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1">User</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="2">Admin</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
      ControlToValidate="ddlRole"                                             
       ErrorMessage="Conform your password." >
   <div style="color:darkred;">
     <span class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" style="color:darkred"></span>
   </div>
   </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

  </div>


  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <label></label>
   <br />

   <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" class="form-control" Width="100%" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" ></asp:Button>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: This is not `asp.net-mvc`

Comment: Can you post your effort so far, and where you got stuck?

Comment: i want user must select  "User" or "Admin" not "--select--" from dropdown list.@evolutionxbox

Comment: Check my answer bellow. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp Code:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="Role" class="form-control" runat="server" onchange="ddlRole_SelectedIndexChanged()">
     <asp:ListItem Value="0">---Select---</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1">User</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="2">Admin</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" class="form-control" Width="100%" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" ></asp:Button>
```

js file:

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> // add this between `head` tag
```

Script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById("btnAdd").disabled = true;

        });

        function ddlRole_SelectedIndexChanged() {

        // Gets your select  value
        var list = document.getElementById("Role").value;

        if(list==0)
        {
             document.getElementById("btnAdd").disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("btnAdd").disabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Hope!!. It helps

Comment: Clean code dude it's working,thanks man,u save my work@User6667769

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It will help you. After pageload, btnAdd button disabled then, user select any listitem value in dropdown list the btnAdd button is enabled except --Select--. If user select the listitem --Select--. btnAdd disabled

Html

```
<body onload="Page_Load()">
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Role" OnChange="Role_SelectedIndexChanged()">
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">User</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Admin</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Role").click(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "0") {
                    $("#btnAdd").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#btnAdd").removeProp("disabled");
                }
            });

        });  

 function Page_Load() {
            $("#btnAdd").prop("disabled", true);
        }
```

Comment: dude it's not helping me,but i got an idea from your code,i do this

Comment: no error,i think onload="Page_Load()" that's not working.

Comment: i got an idea from your code,i do this in my code behind (c#),under page lode and button i put this-                                  
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

     btnAdd.Enabled = false;   
    }                                                                                                                protected void Role_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnAdd.Enabled = true;
    }
        now its working fine,thanks @user688

Answer (score 0):

If you bind to the onchange event of the drop down and then check the value and based on the value disable or enable the button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Role").on("change", function() {
       if ( $(this).val() == "0" ) {
           $("#btnAdd").prop("disabled",true);
        }
        else {
           $("#btnAdd").removeProp("disabled");
          }
   });

});
```

Comment: not working @Avitus Matia,please see my full code above.

Comment: Are you inside of a master page?

Comment: i use validation ValidationGroup="AddUser" and bind Button,dropdown and textbox.u think thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As this is ASP.Net control, so you can add `onchange` event where you can call a javascript function and check the value like this,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Role" class="form-control" runat="server" 
  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRole_SelectedIndexChanged" 
  onchange="myFunction()">
    <asp:ListItem value="0">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="1">User</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="2">Admin</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then in your js,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction()
  {
     var drpdwn = document.getElementById("Role");
     if(drpdwn.options[drpdwn.selectedIndex].value == 0)
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     else
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
  }
</script>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: not working @Basanta Matia,please see my full code above.

Comment: What do u mean by not working ?? Did u check ur browser console ? Any error ? Is it calling ur js function or not ? Did u follow my answer ?

Comment: Do like this in your script, var e = document.getElementById("Role"); Then check the value like, if(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value == 0) { disabled the button here }     Let me know whether its working or not

Comment: ya but when i choose "--Select--" button remain enable.

Comment: k i will inform u.

Comment: i tray this  <script>
            var e = document.getElementById("ddlRole");
            if (e.options[e.selectedIndex].value == 0)
            {
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            else {
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
            }
                
        </script> ,this script disable button for all @ Basanta Matia

Comment: Man what is ddlRole ?? U have set Role as your dropdownlist ID. Then why are you calling ddlRole element.

Comment: ddlRole is Role,i change it here

Comment: .i use validation ValidationGroup="AddUser" and bind Button,dropdown and textbox.u think thats the problem.

Comment: @ Basanta Matia dude i use this as u told me, var e = document.getElementById("Role"); Then check the value like, if(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value == 0) { disabled the button here },but when i use value==0 then for all selection('--Select--,User & Admin') make button disable,but when i put "Value==1" it reverse.

Answer (score 0):

**in my code behind(c#)under page load & button i put this code below, and in .aspx under dropdownlist add AutoPostBack="true" .Have a look @user688 & @User6667769 its working**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    btnAdd.Enabled = false;
}protected void ddlRole_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnAdd.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery or even JS to handle this. Just use your code behind.

```
protected void Role_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnAdd.Enabled = Role.SelectedItem.Value != 0;
}
```

And add `AutoPostBack="true"` to your dropdown.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Role" class="form-control" runat="server" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="Role_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
  <asp:ListItem Value="0">---Select---</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="1">User</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="2">Admin</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" class="form-control" Width="100%" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" ></asp:Button>
```